# Apache superset user list

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to login superset but user/password is invalid.
When I try to change password with below command it says there is no user as 'admin'

```
(supersetdata) ilke@DEVELOPMENT11:~/supersetdata/bin$ export FLASK_APP=superset
(supersetdata) ilke@DEVELOPMENT11:~/supersetdata/bin$ flask fab reset-password --username admin --password admin


Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/home/ilke/supersetdata/bin/superset_config.py]
logging was configured successfully
INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
/home/ilke/supersetdata/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py:191: UserWarning: Flask-Caching: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, caching is effectively disabled.
  warnings.warn(
No PIL installation found
INFO:superset.utils.screenshots:No PIL installation found
User admin not found.
```

How can I list all users in apache superset? I searched but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `flask fab list-users` command will list users with their roles.

```
root@c189c4d2677e:/app# flask fab list-users 
Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/app/docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config.py]
List of users
-------------
username:admin | email:admin@superset.com | role:[Admin]
```